# How do i make existing user a Super User in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have three users created with CREATEDB access. I need to alter them to SUPERUSER.  how do i resolve this ?

I have tried "ALTER USER  WITH superuser;" but I keep getting the below error.

ALTER USER  WITH superuser;

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
ALTER USER  WITH superuser

Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "superuser" 
Position: 25; [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=500310]
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0s**strong text**

Answer (score 5):

Use the following

```
ALTER USER <username> WITH CREATEUSER
```

similarly if you like to take away superuser privilege

```
ALTER USER <username> WITH NOCREATEUSER
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mention `with`, just type

`alter user <username> createuser`

Here is a link to the documentation from aws
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_superusers.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me:

When I logged into the redshift, I simply put `superuser` while connecting and same database name and it worked.

I did not need to write query.